# My jQuery animate() runs 2 times, how to fix this?

Tags: jquery, css

I've made some animation with the `animate` function of jQuery. When the function launches it runs 2 times; the div goes down, goes back up and goes finally go back down.

I dont know how to fix this.

```
$("#p1 br").css("display","none");
$("#p12 br").css("display","none");
$("#p13 br").css("display","none");

$("#cryptosmart").mouseover(function() {
  $("#cryptobox").animate({top: "1403.5px"});
  $("#cryptopass").css("top","1591.5px");
});
$("#cryptosmart").mouseout(function() {
  $("#cryptobox").animate({top: "1201px"});
  $("#cryptopass").css("top","1389px");
});
$("#cryptobox").mouseover(function() {
  $("#cryptopass").css("top","1591.5px");
});
$("#cryptobox").mouseout(function() {
  $("#cryptopass").css("top","1389px");
});
```

Comment: Can you also add your html? Or better yet, edit and click the stack snippet icon and then you can make a working example.

Comment: try `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`
probably one of those elements is child of on another div so it runs two times...

Comment: It is very hard to determine what s wrong without your html code. My guess would be this : You attach a mouseover event on the `#cryptosmart` - Element but within you animate the `cryptobox` - Element. This element has an animation on `mouseover` on its own. My be your second animation gets triggered while the first is running ?!

Comment: Issue aside, it would be better (for a variety of reasons) to perform this animation in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your issue because I didn't see. Can you share jsfiddle/codepen or stack snippets ?

But should you try this with jQuery `hover` function. This function can do with two parameters. Like this;

```
$("#cryptosmart").hover(
    function(){ //mouseenter
        $("#cryptobox").animate({top: "1403.5px"});
        $("#cryptopass").css("top","1591.5px");
    },
    function(){ //mouseleave
        $("#cryptobox").animate({top: "1201px"});
        $("#cryptopass").css("top","1389px");
    }
);
```

Comment: Just FYI hover uses `mouseenter`, not `mouseover`